# Separate context for different stories in storybook

Tags: javascript, frontend, storybook

I'm using storybook to be the showcase of different components. However I've found that the context of different components in storybook are not separated. E.g. in one of the story, I register the mocked services in the Dependency Injection, and in another story, I will get the already injected mocked services from the previous story.

I've also found that the CSS files being imported are also being kept in the memory. If there is some global CSS styles, once it is being imported in the first story, I could also get it in the second one without import it again.

However this is causing problems, e.g. the Dependency Injection library will complain that a service is being injected twice.

It seems that all the stories in the storybook shares the same global context. Is there any way to separate the context, so that each of the stories has its own context which is getting destroyed each time when people switch the story?

Please let me know if you need any extra information, e.g. storybook configuration or so.

Thanks in advance.